# App icon do not appear while installation

Tags: iphone, ios

I have created an app & uploaded on my local server, When I download & install my app on my devic the app icon not appear. Instead it shows only white color. Once installation finishes the app icon becomes visible.

Its happening on both iphone 3gs & iphone 4. Also on OS 4 & 5. Has anyone has faced this kind of issues earlier.

I have checked app icon key in my info.plist file & its correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may either be a bug or simply a change with newer Xcode/iOS versions, you can't do much about this. Anyway, the essential is to have your icon properly appeeared when your app is installed. Also, when your app gets into the AppStore and is downloaded, you won't face this issue anymore -- iOS properly shows the (faded) icon while downloading an application.

Comment: Yes, the icon is appearing once the app is installed. Hope so that this issue don't appear while downloading from appstore.  Thanks for your response.